# Referencing the value of a variable in Fitnesse by using another variable value

Tags: variables, fitnesse

Is it possible to re-use a variable in Fitnesse in referencing another variable:

for example

!define var1 {booking}
!define bookingPeriod {June}

Is there a way to get the value of 'June' for booking period by concatenating var1 and 'period'

I tried the following but it didn't work

${${var1}Period}

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

There are actually two points you need to be aware of.

First, when composing variables you need to use *different* delimiters. FitNesse allows three different sets -- (), {}, [] -- just for that purpose.

Second, it is easier to compose in the definition itself, to wit:

```
!define FileName (${BaseName}.xls)
!define var1 {booking}
!define bookingPeriod $(${var1}June)
```

And then you can use `${bookingPeriod}` in your code.
I recently wrote a series of articles on practical FitNesse tips, published on Simple-Talk.com. [Part 5](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-tools/acceptance-testing-with-fitnesse-symbols,-variables-and-code-behind-styles/) specifically discusses composing variables in this manner.

Comment: Thanks but my question was about the reverse order of steps you described. Basically I want to write  $(${var1}Period) and get the value it could represent i.e. the value of ${bookingPeriod}. This is nested de-referencing and it seems Fitnesse does not support it.

Comment: Ah, you are right; I did not quite answer your question. I just experimented with many variations but I did not find one that will work for your particular case.

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a look at this page? : http://www.fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.FitNesseWiki.MarkupLanguageReference.MarkupVariables